# Credentials are asked to internal users in ASP.NET page

Tags: internet-explorer, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, network-service

Our internal users are being asked to enter their username and passwords to see the homepage. **We want them to use SSO and not get a prompt.**

Here is the details:

- **Windows authentication is enabled**. The rest is disabled (including Anonymous authentication)
- Using default apppool which is **Integrated** and .NET Framework 4.0. Apppool uses **NetworkService** account
- Server and client are in the **same AD domain**
- Using **Internet Explorer** to test
- Making changes in client side is not an option (Trusted sites etc.)

**Note:** If I give users **Read** permission on website's pysical folder, they are not asked to enter credentials. However, I'm trying to figure out why I should give permissions to users since **IIS_IUSRS** has Full Control

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use impersonation to perform operations and access resources with the security context of the authenticated client or of a specific Windows account in your AD and achieve SSO.

To impersonate the internal authenticated user, change your Web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

Comment: I've added the line into web.config and set Impersonation Enabled in IIS. Stil asking credentials